# <OUTDATED> about {{linkTo}} in Ember.js Guide

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I'm reading guide of [Ember.js templates](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/).  In the handlebar part of the first example of above link, they used

```
{{#linkTo posts.post post}}
```

but I thought

```
{{#linkTo posts.post}}
```

would work.

**Why do I need second argument 'post'?**

I read the explanation:

> If the route has a dynamic segment, a model that represents the
>   segment. By default, Ember.js will replace the segment with the value
>   of the object's id property.

but I can't associate this explanation with question above.

Comment: sorry, but link is not working :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `#linkTo` helper takes three parameters.

1. The route, in your case `posts.post`
2. The context, here it is the particular `post` object you are referring to in the loop
3. An options hash (currently `title` is supported)

Because the `posts.post` route is a dynamic route, e.g. it can be for one of a collection of posts, we must provide the `#linkTo` helper with which particular post you are wanting to link to.

Comment: then posts.post in {{#linkTo posts.post post}} isn't related with {{#each post in posts}} but post, posts defined in the router?

Comment: Correct I think you can also use `posts/post`, but don't quote me on that

Answer (score 4):

What the other people said in terms of the arguments passed to the #link-to helper in Ember is accurate here is the link to the documentation for anyone that is looking for more info.

You have the route name that you are linking to and the second argument is providing the model context.

Here is more info:

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_link-to

Comment: fixed the link. the location was changed in the new documentation.

Comment: "model context" is a good way to say it, as you can wrap multiple dynamic values into one object [and serialize it] so you can have multiple dynamic segments.

Answer (score 0):

For me code below works fine:

```
  {{#each model as |book|}}
      <h3>{{#link-to 'book' book}}{{book.title}}{{/link-to}}</h3>
  {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Link-to` has format of *inline* and *block*

Reference: [EmberJS-Template Link To Inline Helper](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/emberjs/temp_link_inlin_helpr.htm)