# Ember Handlebars link-to vs linkTo

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

When you look at a lot of the older (Pre 1.0) Ember code, it seems like the Handlebars helper is `{{#linkTo}}` (see, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453976/about-linkto-in-ember-js-guide) SO post from January 2013). Now, the method seems to be `{{#link-to}}`, based on the [official Ember docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_link-to).

I can't find any mention of when the helper method changed. But I just tried both `{{#link-to}}` and `{{#linkTo}}` in an app using Ember 1.2 and Handlebars 1.1.2 and both work as expected.

Two questions. When did this change occur? I can't find any mention of it in Handlebars [changelogs](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/release-notes.md) or anything that mentions it. And 2, I assume that since `{{#link-to}}` is what's currently in the docs, that's the new way. But there's no deprecation notice. Is there a plan to no longer support `{{#linkTo}}`? If so, when? Which Ember/Handlebars version? For bonus points, link to a an article that talks about that rationale behind this decision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wouldn't find anything about `link-to` in the changelog for Handlebars since it's a helper class for Ember and not included in the main Handlebars library.

According to the [blog post for RC8](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/08/29/ember-1-0-rc8.html#toc_other-improvements) the old syntax has been "soft deprecated". The old method is marked with [@deprecated in the source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.2.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/helpers/link_to.js#L759) but doesn't log anything even if used (not even with `Ember.ENV.RAISE_ON_DEPRECATION` set).

You will also see there that the old one is kept as a straight alias to the new one with no real implementation of it's own.

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('linkTo', Ember.Handlebars.helpers['link-to']);
```

Since they plan to use [semantic versioning](http://semver.org) ([as said in the post for the 1.0 release](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/08/31/ember-1-0-released.html)) for their releases they can't really remove this helper until they hit 2.0 though.

Comment: Thats OK, I'm glad you remembered eventually!

Answer (score 2):

The linkTo and bindAttr are changed to link-to and bind-attr in [this](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/3192) pull request. The hyphenated form was used, because is more close to [web components](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) custom elements syntax. So use the hyphenated form if avaliable in your current version.